# Counting data per user with mongo aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection, where each document contains user_ids as a property, which is an Array field. Example document(s) would be :

```
[{
  _id: 'i3oi1u31o2yi12o3i1',
  unique_prop: 33,
  prop1: 'some string value',
  prop2: 212,
  user_ids: [1, 2, 3 ,4]
},
{
  _id: 'i3oi1u88ffdfi12o3i1',
  unique_prop: 34,
  prop1: 'some string value',
  prop2: 216,
  user_ids: [2, 3 ,4]
},
{
  _id: 'i3oi1u8834432ddsda12o3i1',
  unique_prop: 35,
  prop1: 'some string value',
  prop2: 211,
  user_ids: [2]
}]
```

My goal is to get number of documents per user, so sample output would be :

```
[
 {user_id: 1, count: 1},
 {user_id: 2, count: 3},
 {user_id: 3, count: 2},
 {user_id: 4, count: 2}
]
```

I've tried couple of things none of which worked, lastly I tried :

```
aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { unique_prop: "$unique_prop"},
    users: { "$addToSet": "$user_ids" },
    count: { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
]
```

But it just returned the users per document. I m still trying to learn the any resource or advice would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` the "user_ids" array and in the `$group` stage count the number of time each "id" appears in the collection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$user_ids" }, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$user_ids", "count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB aggregation performs computation on group of values from documents in a collection and return computed result through executing its stages in a pipeline.

According to above mentioned description please try executing following aggregate query in MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: "$user_ids"
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
              _id:{user_id:'$user_ids'},
              total:{$sum:1}
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
                user_id:'$_id.user_id',
                count:'$total'
            }
        },

    ]


);
```

In above aggregate query initially $unwind operator breaks an array field user_ids of each document into multiple documents for each element of  array field and then it groups documents by value of user_ids field contained into each document and performs summation of documents for each value of user_ids field.